# How to give instance specific delay to an udp instance in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module top;
    m m1();
    m m2();
endmodule

module m;
    myudp u1();
endmodule
```

I want to give `delay=5` to `top.m1.u1`
We can do this by making the following change in module m.

```
module m;
    parameter p = 0;
    defparam top.m1.p = 5;
    myudp u1 #(p) u1();
endmodule
```

But this makes `top.m2.u1` zero delay udp. Earlier it was a no-delay udp.

Comment: `myudp #p u1();`

Comment: 1/ In your previous question Dave already told you NOT to use defparam. It is obsolete. 2/ Instead of asking "how do I do X" you should ask "I want to do Y what is the best way". 3/ *"But this makes top.m2.u1 zero delay udp. Earlier it was a no-delay udp."* we have no idea what is in your udp. Probably a delay with a parameter but without code we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

All gatel-level primitives have zero delay by default. i.e. the following are equivalent:

```
myudp u1  u1();
myudp u1 #(0) u1();
```